# Problem with window.open in FireFox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

I have problem with downloading files in Firefox. I tried to find solution in old posts but I didn't find anything.  I understand that solution is very simple, but I think today is not my lucky day :)

Simple example. I try to call a web method from JavaScript and download a file.

Client code:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         function Test() {             
             PageMethods.Test(onCompleted);
         }

         function onCompleted(result) {
             window.open(result);                          
         }         
    </script>

........

 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>  

    <div>
     <input type=button value="Download" onclick="Test()"/>

    </div>
```

Server side:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Test()
{
  return "\\Files\\test.zip";
}
```

Folder 'Files' lies in root folder of Web application.

For IE and Chrome, this code is working fine, and I can download the file.  But in Firefox, I get an error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

and in url I can see for example:
http://localhost:1406/\Files\test.zip

How can I return the correct path to zip file?

Comment: Is this file located on your internal network, on at an internet-accessible location?

Comment: you might just need to make your "\\" be "/"

Comment: Have you tried using forward slash characters instead of backslashes? You're forming a URL, after all, and backslashes are not valid separators in URLs.

Comment: Avitus, Pointy, your answers is good for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

URL don´t allow for backslashes.

If the file is located at \Files\test.zip on your windows webserver root the correct url to the file is http:///Files/test.zip

Answer (score 0):

Change the server side code to:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Test()
{
    return "/Files/test.zip";
}
```

Web URLs should use forward-slashes instead of backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use [ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) method of the System.Web.UI.Control class. But in case of static method there is some [workaround solutions](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/18/ResolveUrl-without-Page).

Answer (score -2):

Replacing the following lines

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Test()
{
  return "\\Files\\test.zip";
}
```

with these might work...

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Test()
{
  return "\\\\Files\\test.zip";
}
```

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but perhaps it was because the string is already escaped using C# conventions.

Comment: Well I didn't downvote but your answer definitely won't help - you've added *more* backslashes, but what needs to be done is to change to "/" characters instead.

Comment: adding more backslashes would render it the same way. the four backslashes would be considered as two escape sequences and the path he would get eventually is: `\\Files\Test.zip`, which was what he was looking for...