# Firefox appending URL in window.open

Tags: firefox, window.open

I have a file on my network that I need to reach from my web page.

In IE I just do:

```
window.open(url,name,'height=300,width=550,resizable,menubar,scrollbars=yes');
```

and it works, it opens a small window and then pops up the "file open" dialogue.

In Firefox I do the same and it appends my url to the current page's url and gives the obvious error of NOT_FOUND.

The url I pass is along the lines of

```
\\pipeline\sampleData\testDoc.doc
```

In Firefox I get:

```
http://site.com/FileAccess/\\pipeline\sampleData\testDoc.doc
```

Any ideas? This is actually the second instance of this same problem in the past week that I have run into.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the actual address of the testDoc file in the URL field of `window.open()`

```
var url = "file:///C:/pipeline/sampleData/testDoc.doc";
```

where `C:/pipeline/sampleData/testDoc.doc` is the actual location of the file.

If its the relative path then.. then specify the path relative to the current location.

```
var url = "pipeline/sampleData/testDoc.doc"
```

This will append the url to the current file location.

Comment: The url given is fixed, the path will be different for each document and I cannot expect the users to map drives to different network paths. The url is coming from a database pointing to millions of different records on the network. Again, this works in Internet Explorer, so I am not sure if it is supposed to work in Firefox or if it is a bug that it is able to work in IE.

Comment: You might want to check the discussions in the below links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022838/problem-with-window-open-in-firefox  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082424/how-to-let-firefox-treat-forward-and-back-slashes-the-same-in-url-or-file-paths

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `\` is not a URL path separator.  You want to be using `/pipeline/sampleData/testDoc.doc` or something along those lines, depending on what your site paths look like.